# unordered_set example compiler error (hash and equivalence function error possibily)

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, std, unordered-set

I am trying to compile this code in C++11 and it gives me compile errors:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std; 

class Point{
  int x,y; 
 public: 
  Point(int a=0, int b=0): x(a), y(b) {}; 
  int getX(void){ return x;} 
  int getY(void){ return y;} 
};


class monkeyHash{
 public: 
    size_t operator()(const Point & xy){
        size_t h1 = std::hash<int>()(xy.getX()); 
        size_t h2 = std::hash<int>()(xy.getY());
        return (h1 ^ (h2<<1));  
 }
};

struct monkeyEquals{
 bool operator()(const Point & lhs, const Point & rhs){
     return (lhs.getX() == rhs.getX()) && (lhs.getY() == rhs.getY()); 
 }
};

int main(){
  unordered_set<Point,monkeyHash,monkeyEquals> visited; 
  visited.insert(Point(0,0));   

}
```

The error message I get is really long so I will summarize it:

```
In member function ‘size_t monkeyHash::operator()(const Point&)’:
monkey.cpp:26:50: error: passing ‘const Point’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int    Point::getX()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
monkey.cpp:27:50: error: passing ‘const Point’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Point::getY()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
monkey.cpp: In member function ‘bool monkeyEquals::operator()(const Point&, const Point&)’:
```

And it also seems to complain about my hash function. Is the way that I am hashing incorrect? 
I am still very new to template, c++11 and STL, so sorry if the issue is very noobish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare those methods `const`:

```
int getX(void) const { return x; }
int getY(void) const { return y; }
```

Using `const` like this, tells the compiler that the method will not change the class instance. Only then you can call it on a `const Point` object.

In C++11 you might also want to mark them `noexcept`, (e.g. `int getX() const noexcept { return x; }`, because they don't throw any exceptions. If you mark them `noexcept`, the compiler might have the chance to optimize your code a bit more.

The same goes for the `size_t monkeyHash::operator()(const Point &)` and `bool monkeyEquals::operator()(const Point &, const Point &)`methods.

PS: You can probably get rid of the `monkeyEquals` class if you instead overload `operator==` in `class Point {}`:

```
inline bool operator==(const Point & rhs) const noexcept
{ return (x == rhs.x) && (y == rhs.y); }
```

You can also override `operator!=`:

```
inline bool operator!=(const Point & rhs) const noexcept
{ return (x != rhs.x) || (y != rhs.y); }
```

See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_associative_containers_%28C++%29#Custom_hash_functions) on how to write a better custom hash function in namespace `std`.

If you take the advice in this post-scriptum, you can declare your container like this:

```
unordered_set<Point> visited;
```

Comment: `operator()` on `monkeyHash` and `monkeyEquals` should be `const` as well.

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to resolve the first issue. However, still hash problems.

Comment: jotik your answer is very comprehensive, thanks! I found one issue size_t h1 = std::hash<int>(xy.getX()); 
size_t h2 = std::hash<int>(xy.getY());  did not compile so I modified it to:  std::hash<int> hash_int;
            size_t h1 = hash_int(xy.getX()); 
            size_t h2 = hash_int(xy.getY());
and now it works. by the way, if I want to find an element, say Point(0,0) which I just inserted, do I write   if(visited.find(Point(0,0)))
      cout << "yes" ; 
   else
      cout << "no";  because that didn't seem to work.

Comment: never mind the second part of the question. find iterates through the container, does not return boolean. So my condition has to be if(visited.find(Point(0,0))!= visited.end())